# javascript to filter unwanted data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to angular js. I have a link http://www.bursamalaysia.com/searchbox_data.json that I want to get a list of name and id.

I able to get the list from a link in json but I need to filter unwanted items in the list. If the id is more than 4 digits, then remove full_name,name, short_name and id. example: if id:123456 , it need to be filter out, together with name,short name.

**app.js**

```
  abc: {
      name: "Momo",
      value: "kls",
      long: "KLSE",
      searchRef: KLSE_SEARCH_REF,
      searchRefURL: "http://www.bursamalaysia.com/searchbox_data.json",

    },
```

**details.js**

```
$ionicLoading.show();

if ($scope.currentMarket == "abc"){

    $webServicesFactory.getNotParsed($marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].searchRefURL).then(function success(response){
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        for (var i = 0; i < response[0].length; i++){
            $scope.searchRef.push({
              name: response[0][i].name || response[0][i].full_name,
              symbol: response[0][i].short_name,
              code: response[0][i].id,
              market: $marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].long
            });
        }
        console.info($scope.searchRef);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in searchItems" ng-click="openDetail(item)">
        <p>{{item.symbol}} - {{item.name}}</p>
        <p>{{currentMarket | uppercase}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try anything? You can do this easily with basic Javascript condition checking.

Comment: you can use `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.map`

Comment: @Miro can you elaborate more in answer?

Comment: @Hoyen I think of using length of the id, If >4,remove it, but I do not how to write it in angularjs

Comment: @bkcollection here is example `$scope.searchRef = response[0].filter(item=> item.id.length<5)`

Comment: @bkcollection your problem has nothing to do with angularjs. It is solved by basic Javascript logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.map`, which is quite elegant.

```
$ionicLoading.show();
  if($scope.currentMarket == "abc") {
    $webServicesFactory.getNotParsed($marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].searchRefURL).then(
      function success(response) {
        $scope.searchRef = JSON.parse(response)[0].filter(function(itm) {
            // whatever you want to filter should pass this condition
            return itm.id.toString().length <= 3; 
        }).map(function(itm) {
            // for each item, transform to this
            return {
              name: itm.name || itm.full_name,
              symbol: itm.short_name,
              code: itm.id,
              market: $marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].long
            };
        });

        $ionicLoading.hide();
      }
    );
  }
```

Make sure to handle any errors and to make your code defensive.

Comment: This should also better for performance than pushing many times to the array in the scope, because the Angular digest cycle only gets triggered once.

Answer (score 0):

if you need filter more than 4 digit id values , then you can restrict with simple condition `if(response[0][i].id <= 999)`
example below:

```
for(var i=0; i<response[0].length; i+=1){
   if(response[0][i].id.toString().length <= 3 ) {
      $scope.searchRef.push(
        {
          name: response[0][i].name || response[0][i].full_name,
          symbol: response[0][i].short_name,
          code: response[0][i].id,
          market: $marketProvider[$scope.currentMarket].long
        }
      );
    }
    }
```

Comment: `if(response[0][i].id <= 999)` is keep 4 digits or remove 4 digits? I want to remove more than 4 digits

Comment: yes, if id is below or equal to 999, then only condition will be true and push object to $scope.searchRef array variable. so $scope.searchRef  have values rest of above 4 digits id values

Comment: Can it be using length of the id? please advice. Some id is '3074LA' which is not a  number

Comment: oh so you can use this condition `if(response[0][i].id.toString().length <= 3 )` instead of this `if(response[0][i].id <= 999)`